# calculate difference and percentage

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have following data , numbers recruited/applied for a particular office, and would like to find the difference between previous and current year and their percentage increase or decrease.

Mentioned the formulas to use in brackets in expected output.

```
Office      year        recruited       applied
Pune        2015            10            15
Pune        2016            7             20
Mumbai      2015            10            23
Mumbai      2016            15            18
```

My expected output should be like:

```
Office      Difference      %recruited
Pune        -3  (7-10)      -30%(7-10/10)
Mumbai      5(15-10)         50%
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using SQL Server 2012 or higher you could use the LAG (or LEAD) function. Since you aren't you can get creative with a CTE. This approach is taken from http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/.

```
SELECT 'Pune' AS Office,
'2015' AS year,
10 AS recruited,
15 AS applied
INTO #Temp
UNION 
SELECT 'Pune' AS Office,
'2016' AS year,
7 AS recruited,
20 AS applied
UNION 
SELECT 'Mumbai' AS Office,
'2015' AS year,
10 AS recruited,
23 AS applied
UNION 
SELECT 'Mumbai' AS Office,
'2016' AS year,
15 AS recruited,
18 AS applied;

WITH cte AS (
SELECT rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.office ORDER BY t.year), * FROM #Temp t)
SELECT cte.office, cte.recruited - prv.recruited AS DifferenceRecruited,
((cte.recruited - prv.recruited) / CONVERT(FLOAT, prv.recruited) * 100) AS RecruitedChangePercentage,
cte.applied - prv.applied AS DifferenceApplied,
((cte.applied - prv.applied) / CONVERT(FLOAT, prv.applied) * 100) AS AppliedChangePercentage
  FROM cte
LEFT JOIN cte prv ON prv.Office = cte.office AND prv.rownum = cte.rownum - 1
WHERE prv.recruited IS NOT null
ORDER BY cte.Office DESC
```

Hope this helps.